# How to declare and malloc pointer inside OpenMP parallel region? (ERROR: Segment violation ('core' generated))

Tags: c, openmp

I am doing it like:

```
void calculateClusterCentroIDs(int numCoords, int numObjs, int numClusters, float * dataSetMatrix, int * clusterAssignmentCurrent, float *clustersCentroID) {

    int * clusterMemberCount = (int *) calloc (numClusters,sizeof(int));

    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        int ** localClusterMemberCount;
        int * activeCluster;
        #pragma omp single
        {
            localClusterMemberCount = (int **) malloc (omp_get_num_threads() * sizeof(int *));
            //localClusterMemberCount[0] = (int *) calloc (omp_get_num_threads()*numClusters,sizeof(int));
            for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_num_threads(); ++i) {
                localClusterMemberCount[i] = calloc (numClusters,sizeof(int));
                //localClusterMemberCount[i] = localClusterMemberCount[i-1] + numClusters;
            }
            activeCluster = (int *) calloc (omp_get_num_threads(),sizeof(int));
        }

        // sum all points
        // for every point
        for (int i = 0; i < numObjs; ++i) {
            // which cluster is it in?
            activeCluster[omp_get_thread_num()] = clusterAssignmentCurrent[i];
            // update count of members in that cluster
            ++localClusterMemberCount[omp_get_thread_num()][activeCluster[omp_get_thread_num()]];
            // sum point coordinates for finding centroid
            for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
#pragma omp atomic
                clustersCentroID[activeCluster[omp_get_thread_num()]*numCoords + j] += dataSetMatrix[i*numCoords + j];
        }

        // now divide each coordinate sum by number of members to find mean/centroid
        // for each cluster
        for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; ++i) {
            if (localClusterMemberCount[omp_get_thread_num()][i] != 0)
                // for each numCoordsension
                for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
#pragma omp atomic
                    clustersCentroID[i*numCoords + j] /= localClusterMemberCount[omp_get_thread_num()][i];  /// XXXX will divide by zero here for any empty clusters!
        }

        // free memory
        #pragma omp single
        {
            free (localClusterMemberCount[0]);
            free (localClusterMemberCount);
            free (activeCluster);
        }
    }
    free(clusterMemberCount);
```

But I get the error: `Segment violation ('core' generated)` so I am doing something bad, and I think the error is on mallocing pointers due to I have tried sequential code and it is working fine. Also I have tried parallel code but without mallocs (using globals variables with atomic) and that works fine too. The error only apears when I try to create private pointers and malloc them.

Any idea how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons for the segfault:

- `localClusterMemberCount` should be a shared variable declared outside of the parallel region, initialized within the parallel region by a single thread. Otherwise, each thread has its own copy of the variable, and for all but the thread that has gone through the `single`section, that points to a random location of the memory.
- An implicit or explicit barrier is needed before the section of code where pointers are freed. All threads needs to be done for sure before memory can be disallocated, otherwise one thread may free pointers still being used by other threads.

There are few other issues with the code. See below with my own comments flagged with `***`:

```
void calculateClusterCentroIDs(int numCoords, int numObjs, int numClusters, float * dataSetMatrix, int * clusterAssignmentCurrent, float *clustersCentroID) {

    int * clusterMemberCount = (int *) calloc (numClusters,sizeof(int));

    /* ***
     * This has to be a shared variable that each thread can access
     * If declared inside the parallel region, it will be a thread-local variable
     * which is left un-initialized for all but one thread. Further attempts to access
     * that variable will lead to segfaults
     */
    int ** localClusterMemberCount;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(localClusterMemberCount,clusterMemberCount)
    {

        // *** Make activeCluster a thread-local variable rather than a shared array (shared array will result in false sharing)
        int activeCluster;
        #pragma omp single
        {
            localClusterMemberCount = (int **) malloc (omp_get_num_threads() * sizeof(int *));
            //localClusterMemberCount[0] = (int *) calloc (omp_get_num_threads()*numClusters,sizeof(int));
            for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_num_threads(); ++i) {
                localClusterMemberCount[i] = calloc (numClusters,sizeof(int));
                //localClusterMemberCount[i] = localClusterMemberCount[i-1] + numClusters;
            }
        }

        // sum all points
        // for every point
        for (int i = 0; i < numObjs; ++i) {
            // which cluster is it in?
            activeCluster = clusterAssignmentCurrent[i];
            // update count of members in that cluster
            ++localClusterMemberCount[omp_get_thread_num()][activeCluster];
            // sum point coordinates for finding centroid

            // *** This may be slower in parallel because of the atomic operation
            for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
                #pragma omp atomic
                clustersCentroID[activeCluster*numCoords + j] += dataSetMatrix[i*numCoords + j];
        }

        /* ***
         * Missing: one reduction step
         * The global cluster member count needs to be updated
         * one option is below :
         */
         #pragma omp critical
         for (int i=0; i < numClusters; ++i) clusterMemberCount+=localClusterMemberCount[omp_get_thread_num()];
         #pragma omp barrier // wait here before moving on



        // *** The code below was wrong; to compute the average, coordinates should be divided by the global count
        // *** Sucessive divisions by local count will fail. Like, 1/(4+6) is not the same as (1/4)/6

        // now divide each coordinate sum by number of members to find mean/centroid
        // for each cluster
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < numClusters; ++i) {
            if (clusterMemberCount != 0)
                // for each numCoordsension
                #pragma omp simd //not sure this will help, the compiler may already vectorize that
                for (int j = 0; j < numCoords; ++j)
                    clustersCentroID[i*numCoords + j] /= clusterMemberCount[i];  /// XXXX will divide by zero here for any empty clusters!
                    // *** ^^ atomic is not needed
                    // *** only one thread will access each value of clusterCentroID

        }

        #pragma omp barrier
        /* ***
         * A barrier is needed otherwise the first thread arriving there will start to free the memory
         * Other threads may still be in the previous loop attempting to access localClusterMemberCount
         * If the pointer has been freed already, this will result in a segfault
         *
         * With the corrected code, the implicit barrier at the end of the distributed
         * for loop would be sufficient. With your initial code, an explicit barrier 
         * would have been needed.
         */

        // free memory
        #pragma omp single
        {
            // *** Need to free all pointers and not only the first one
            for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_num_threads(); ++i) free (localClusterMemberCount[i]);
            free (localClusterMemberCount);
        }
    }
    free(clusterMemberCount);
```

Comment: Now the code is working. It lose a lot of troughput due to barriers and criticals, but that is other problem. Declarations and mallocing are working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: `numCoords` is 13 and `numObjs` is 239108